# An application of Compactness and Ramsey theorem

Tags: logic, compactness, model-theory

**Definition**: A formula $\varphi(x,y)$ has $VC_{ind}-density ≤ r$ for $r ∈ R$ if there is $K \in \omega$ such that for every ﬁnite and indiscernible sequence $\overline{b} = \langle b_i : i < N \rangle  ∈ M^{|y|·N}$, $|S_{\varphi}(range(\overline{b}))| < K · N^r$. We denote this by $VC_{ind} ≤ r$.
(Where $S_{\varphi}(A)$ is the set of all $\varphi$-types over A for for $A \subseteq M^{|y|}$, such that $M$ is the underlying set of the monster model $\mathcal{M}$ of the complete theory $T$.)

Now suppose $VC_{ind} \geq d$, for some positive $d \in \omega$. Let $0 < \epsilon < 1/2$. ***How*** we could show By **compactness**, **Ramsey’s theorem**, and saturation of the monster model, there is some indiscernible sequence $\langle a_i \rangle_{i \in \mathbb{R}}$ such that $|S_{\varphi}(A)| ≥ |A|^{d−\epsilon}$ for arbitrarily large ﬁnite $A ⊆ \langle a_i \rangle_{i \in \mathbb{R}}$.

Would be grateful for your hints or solutions.

Comment: Could you give some background? Is this related to the Vapnik-Chervonenkis dimension?

Comment: Yes, it is related to VC dimension. It's part of a proof of the fact that $VCm(\varphi) = VC_{ind}(\varphi)$, which I was stuck in! I could add any specific details if you request.

Answer (score 1):

I may edit (or delete) this (sketch of an) answer in the next days.

Note that for each $n$ there is a first order formula $\vartheta_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ such that

$$M\models\vartheta_n(a_1,\dots,a_n)\ \Leftrightarrow\ |S_{\varphi}(a_1,\dots,a_n)| ≥ n^{d−\varepsilon}$$

The formula $\vartheta_n(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ may be horribly long. For instance, for $d=2$, when $\varepsilon$ is sufficiently small, $\vartheta_2(a_1,a_2)$ should say that $|S_{\varphi}(a_1,a_2)|=4$, that is, that

$$\varphi(x,a_1)^{\eta_1}\wedge\varphi(x,a_2)^{\eta_2}$$

is consistent for every $\eta_1,\eta_2\in\{0,1\}$. As usual, $\varphi^0=\neg\varphi$ and $\varphi^1=\varphi$.

Let $p(x_i :i<\omega)$ be the type that contains all these formulas. Every finite subset of $p(x_i :i<\omega)$ is satisfied by indiscernible sequences of arbitrary finite length. Therefore  $p(x_i :i<\omega)$ is satisfied by an infinite indiscernible sequence of order-type $\omega$. It is standard to stretch this sequence to a sequence of order type $\mathbb R$  with the same EM-type.

P.S. Your definition is taken from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.5446.pdf). Correct? It is a rather technical article which assumes a wealth of prerequisites.

Comment: Dear @Escherica, could you please give more detailed proof!

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer, although I'm having some questions still. In fact the article I was studying is [this paper]
                                                                
(https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.5446.pdf), however the article you mentioned is related to the topic.

Comment: Indeed, that is the paper I meant! I amended the link (a cut and paste error).

Comment: Could you please explain more about the (first order) formula $\vartheta(x_1, . . . , x_n)$! and I can't see if you've used the Ramsey theorem actually!

Comment: That formula is just a lengty but straightforward formalization of the definition of $S_\varphi(A)$. (I have added a missing definition in my annswer.)

Comment: The Ramsey Theorem is not necessary because you start with $VC_{ind}$-density. I.e. you start with finite sequences of indiscernibles. (Hunter Johnson might be wrong on this point - ask him.) Ramsey Theorem is required in other parts of the proof of $VC_{ind}=VCm$.